# Cube Deployment failed in BIDS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bids, olap-cube

So I've been doing a project at my university with BIDS and a database on their servers. I've managed to back up the database and put it on my local machine.

Problem right now is I've installed SQL Server 2008 + BIDS through SQL Server 2008 Express Edition. Now I've heard it doesn't include SQL Server Analysis Service, meaning I can't deploy the cube.

I've tried deploying the project on my home computer but it gives me the error.

```
Error   23  The project could not be deployed to the 'my computer 
name\SQLEXPRESS' server because of the following connectivity problems :
A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service 
is running.  To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on 
the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the 
Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.
```

I've checked and SQL browser service is definitely running so I'm not sure what else to try. Is there any way for me to successfully deploy the cube?

Comment: This [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917670.aspx) on troubleshooting SSAS connectivity issues might help.

Comment: @REMAG Joe, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think its authentication issue for your current user connecting to SQLEXPRESS. Try using `"Runas /user:[domain]\[user] "Path to BIDS"` to run BIDS as privileged user and try windows authentication.